# Matplotlib annotations not showing up

Tags: python, matplotlib, anaconda, spyder

I have a scatter plot where I have specified legends and x and y labels however my tick marks, legend, and x and y axis labels do not show up when I plot.  I am using the most recent version of the Anaconda python distribution and running my files directly in Spyder.  If I run the script inside of IDLE then everything shows up as it should.  A stripped down version of my plot is as follows:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy
from matplotlib import rc


CA_90_60 = ([(1.3495843761596 , 0.186363275611754)])
CA_90_120 = ([(26.5436500747458 , 3.66551548830712)])

clearanceline_co = [2,2,1.9,1.8,1.7,1.6,1.5,1.4,1.3,1.2,1.1,1,0.9,0.8,0.7,0.6,0.5,0.4,0.3,0.2,0.1,10e-8,0]
clearanceline_eu = [0,10e-8,0.005,0.01,0.015,0.02,0.025,0.03,0.035,0.04,0.045,0.05,0.055,0.06,0.065,0.07,0.075,0.08,0.085,0.09,0.095,0.1,0.1]
y_co = [1,1,1,1,1,1,1e-1,1e-2,1e-3,0]
x_co = [0,1e-4,1e-3,1e-2,1e-1,1e0,1e0,1e0,1e0,1e0]

plt.rcParams['legend.loc'] = 'best'
plt.figure(1)

n = plt.scatter(*zip(*CA_90_60) , c=numpy.random.rand(3,1) , marker= '+',s=100)
o = plt.scatter(*zip(*CA_90_120) , c=numpy.random.rand(3,1) , marker= '+',s=100)
clearance, = plt.plot(clearanceline_eu, clearanceline_co, color='g')

rc('text', usetex=True)
plt.ylim(10e-5, 10e4)
plt.xlim(10e-6, 10e3)
plt.loglog()
plt.xlabel('Europium (ppm)')
plt.ylabel('Cobalt (ppm)')
plt.legend([n, o, clearance], 
           [ "60 min at 90 kW" , "120 min at 90 kW" , r'$\Sigma = \frac{C_i}{CL} = 1.0$' ] , scatterpoints = 1)
print('plots created')
plt.show()
```

How can I get my plots to show up correctly within Spyder?

Edit:  Here are some version numbers of the packages I am using with their locations:

matplotlib version 1.4.2 in Spyder and from idle

matplotlib location(spyder and idle):/Users/steve/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/**init**.pyc

NumPy also checks out as the same version and location in both IDLE and Spyder.

Comment: Do you get any kind of error message in spyder? I copied your code to idle and got quite a long error message, ending with an error concerning C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\texmanager.py ...

Comment: No errors on my end with both IDLE and Spyder.  I copied and pasted the code from the post just to make sure I didn't transcribe something incorrectly.  It looks like the error you are getting has something to do with LaTeX, perhaps you don't have it installed?  If you change the third entry in the legend that starts with r' to something like "asdf" and then comment out the rc line above plt.ylim that should remove everything that uses LaTeX and it might work.

Comment: Can you add some bits to your scripts to print out the library locations and versions of everything you're using, and do it in and outside of spyder please

Comment: Added them in the main post.  They all check out to be the same versions and locations.

Comment: It's likely that it's the `rc('text', usetex=True)` that is the culprit. Comment that line, restart Spyder, and see what you get (btw you should still get nice symbols in your math regions).  To successfully turn on TeX I think you have to make sure of some other system settings.

Comment: (*Spyder dev here*) It's strange that things work in IDLE and not in Spyder. Are you using the IPython console with the inline backend? What happens if you first run `%matplotlib qt` in the IPython console and run your script again? In any case, I tested your example on Linux and everything is working fine.

Comment: Commenting out the rc('text') line does fix it but only if I restart Spyder.  I was using the OSX backend and switched it over to Qt. I still get the same result, that same line must be commented out.  Not exactly sure why though, I'm moving over from Canopy (Spyder is a way better editor I think) and I always have to have that line in order to get TeX working.  It must be something with the packages Anaconda installs or doesn't install.